# How is possible to remove joomla content quickicons from the admin

Tags: menu, joomla-3.6

We are using K2 for the content in Joomla 3.6.5. We have created a plugin to add K2 quickicons to the list in the admin control panel, but we'd like to remove the joomla content quickicons from the list too as users keep adding content under joomla rather than under K2. In the mod_quickicon helper file for the function getButtons it is written:

> This method returns the array by reference so it can be used to add
>   custom buttons or remove default ones.

How can we access this function in our plugin to remove the joomla content links?

Thanks, James

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you can remove the content's quickicons from the quickicon module. As a workaround you could disable the quickicon module and create a new administrator (custom) module and place it in the "icon" position.

Comment: That is one solution. We y are using another solution which is to make and override in /administrator/templates/isis/html/mod_quickicon/default.php to achieve our aims. But since we have a plugin to add icons we'd like to know how a plugin can remove the standard icons as it would appear possible after reading the quickicons helper file.